# Use regex to extract substrings delimited by another substring

Tags: regex, delimiter

I'm trying to use a regular expression to capture substrings delimited by another substring. For example, if I had the sentence

> My cat is a cat.

and the delimiter I wanted to use was "cat", the output should be

> My
>
> is a
>
> .

I've been unable to find a solution where the delimiter isn't a single character.

Edit: I'm writing this in Java, and the output represents groups returned by Java's Matcher class in a call like "myMatcher.group()". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Where have you been searching and what were the search keywords? I mean: language? tool? What you tried?

Comment: Tushar's approach [works like this](https://regex101.com/r/lF9pV0/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm writing this in Java, and I was unclear with the output. I meant that each of those lines should be a group if one were using the Java Matcher class (i.e. myMatcher.group() ).

Comment: @Grandfather-Paradox: Why do you want to use a Matcher if you need to *split* a string? Sorry, your question is way too unclear.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Each substring should be returned as a match to the pattern I'm trying to write. If I'm understanding correctly, there are three cases: the substring has "cat" on both of its boundaries, it has the left end of the string (^) on one boundary and "cat" on the other, and it has "cat" on one boundary and the right side of the string on the other ($). The substring shouldn't include the word "cat" either; cat should be the delimiter. I know this can be accomplished with StringTokenizer, but I'm more interested in the regex solution.

Comment: Here is the correct approach - https://ideone.com/DnegWt

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was unclear that I know how to use String's .split() method as well as StringTokenizer. I'm really just interested in how a regex would accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So, somewhat more simply, it could be represented with this pseudo-regex as: (^ or cat)(substring that does not include "cat")(cat or $).

Comment: You should know that what you mean is not practical, and this makes no sense since you are using Java. Here is what I think you want: http://ideone.com/748GeU.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `String#split` as Tushar pointed out in the comment.

```
String s = "My cat is a cat.";
String[] res = s.split("cat");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

**This is the only correct way to do it.**

Now, you want to know how to match any text other than `cat` with the `Matcher`.

**DISCLAIMER**: do not use it in Java since it is highly impractical and non-performance-wise.

You may match the `cat` and capture it into a Group, and add another alternative to the pattern that will match any text other than `cat`.

```
String s = "My cat is a cat.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(cat)|[^c]*(?:c(?!at)[^c]*)*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) == null) {      // Did we match "cat"?
        if (!matcher.group(0).isEmpty()) //  Is the match text NOT empty?  System.out.println(matcher.group(0));        //    Great, print it
    }
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/748GeU)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive inline modifier
- `(cat)` - Group 1 capturing a substring `cat`
- `|` - or
- `[^c]*(?:c(?!at)[^c]*)*` - a substring that is not a starting point for a `cat` substring. It is an unrolled `(?s)(?:(?!cat).)*` [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

  - `[^c]*` - 0+ chars other than `c` or `C`
  - `(?:c(?!at)[^c]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:
  - `c(?!at)` - `c` or `C` not followed with `at`, `At`, `AT`, `aT`
  - `[^c]*` - 0+ chars other than `c` or `C`